# Using poswap (translate-toolkit) brakes output encoding

Tags: python, translation, poedit, translate-toolkit

I'm trying to use the [poswap](http://docs.translatehouse.org/projects/translate-toolkit/en/latest/commands/poswap.html) from [Translate Toolkit](http://docs.translatehouse.org/projects/translate-toolkit/en/latest/index.html).

My input file is `he.po` (Hebrew) and my output file is `ar.po` (Arabic)

The result of the following command `poswap he.po ar.po`, is a new `ar.po` file where the source is hebrew and the translation is arabic.

**BUT,** when I open the file using `poedit` all of the source strings encoding fail to comply. Its definitely not `utf-8` anymore..

Does anyone notices that behavior before?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had this problem before.
If you open the `ar.po` file using a text editor, you will see there is a difference between the file headers.

That's because `poswap` is not converting the poedit header as well.

To solve this, just open `ar.po` file using any file editor and add the following to the top:

```
msgid ""
msgstr ""
"Project-Id-Version: \n"
"POT-Creation-Date: \n"
"PO-Revision-Date: \n"
"Last-Translator: \n"
"Language-Team: \n"
"Language: ar\n"
"MIME-Version: 1.0\n"
"Content-Type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8\n"
"Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit\n"
```

Notice the `"Language: ar\n"` line.

This will ensure the po file will have the proper headers.

Good Luck!